# Reading and analyzing budget and transaction data from user input and .csv

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for ideas on how to optimize the following code. I don't really know how to condense anything, I'm still very new to coding and this is the first time I've really created anything besides "Hello World".

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

#Method that calculates the Current Budget of the contents in the .csv file
def currentBudget():
    fileTransaction = open("transactions.csv", "r")
    info = fileTransaction.readlines()
    fileTransaction.close()
    budget = 0
    for line in info[1:]:
        budget += float(line.split(",")[2])
    print("\nCurrent Budget €"+str(budget)+"\n")

#Introductory using ASCII Markdown for Headers
def introduction():
    print("Budgetísimo".center(120,"-"))
    print("Welcome to Budgetísimo, a personal budget application that allows you to record and keep track of all your transaction\n")

#Choices of the User 
def userChoice():
    print("What would you like to do: ")
    print("(a) Record a Transaction")
    print("(b) Calculate Current Budget")
    print("(c) Exit Programme")

def userTransactionOutputOption():
    print("Please select one of the following options: ")
    print("(a) View Transactions using Date Range")
    print("(b) View specific Number of Transactions")

def transactionDate():
    data = pd.read_csv('transactions.csv', sep=",", index_col=0)

    data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)
    
    userStartDate = input("Start Date (DD-MM-YYYY): ")
    userEndDate = input("End Date (DD-MM-YYYY): ")

    afterStartDate = data["Date"] >= userStartDate
    beforeEndDate = data["Date"] <= userEndDate
    beweenDates = afterStartDate & beforeEndDate
    filteredDates = data.loc[beweenDates].sort_values(by="Date")
    print(filteredDates)

#The code
def userInputs():

    prompt = True

    while prompt == True:
        
        userInput = input("\nEnter your Choice: ").lower()
        df = pd.read_csv('transactions.csv', sep=",", index_col=0)
        dfData = pd.DataFrame(df)    

        if userInput == "a":
            fileTransaction = open("transactions.csv", "a", newline="")
            print("Please enter the following data when prompted to do so: ")
            userDescription = input("Description: ")
            fileTransaction.write(userDescription+",")
            userDate = input("Date (DD-MM-YYYY): ")
            fileTransaction.write(userDate+",")
            userAmount = input("Amount: ")
            fileTransaction.write(userAmount+"\n")
            currentBudget()
            print("Your Transaction has been recorded! :) \n")  
            fileTransaction.close()

        elif userInput == "b":
            currentBudget()

            transactionHistory = input("Would you like to see your Transaction History? (Y/N): ").lower()
            if transactionHistory == "y":
                userTransactionOutputOption()
                userTransactionOutput = input("Enter your Choice: ").lower()
                if userTransactionOutput == "a":
                    transactionDate()
                elif userTransactionOutput == "b":    
                    howManyTransaction = int(input("Please specify how many Transactions you want the System to Return: "))
                    print("\nYour Last "+str(howManyTransaction)+" Transactions: ")
                    print(df.tail(howManyTransaction))   
                else:
                    print("Please enter A (Date Range), B (Specific Transaction).")
                
            elif transactionHistory == "n":
                print("Your Last 10 Transactions: ")
                print(df.tail(-10).sort_values(by="Date"))
            else:
                print("Please enter Y (yes) or N (No).")

        elif userInput == "c":
            prompt = False
            print("\nProgramme Terminated\n")
            exit()

        else:
            print("Please enter A (Transaction Input), B (Transaction Output), C (Exit Programme).")
```

I am unsure how to reduce it, I have a file called app.py where I put the methods, but there is one method that contains what is essentially the entire code. I know this is not really good practice, but this is the first time doing anything like this and I'm really lost on what I should be doing. If anyone could help that would be amazing! :)

Comment: I really liked that you grouped related `print`s in functions to call repeatedly! One thing you might consider is factoring the different actions you take, depending on the `userInput` variable, into separate functions. That way, the body of your main function is cleaner and easier to read, and then you have a separate function for each functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Good first effort!

**On `currentBudget`**:

One of the things that is easy to tell you about is Python's context managers [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

The context manager lets you write code in a different context and takes care of preparing that context and cleaning it up. In your case, there's a context to deal with opened files :)

So, instead of

```py
def currentBudget():
    fileTransaction = open("transactions.csv", "r")
    info = fileTransaction.readlines()
    fileTransaction.close()
    # ...
```

it is recommended that you do

```py
def currentBudget():
    with open("transactions.csv", "r") as f:
        info = fileTransaction.readlines()
    # ...
```

The context manager makes sure the file is properly closed even if the code raises an error.
Generally, inside the `with` statement you write the least amount of code possible, so that the context can get cleaned up ASAP.

Also, if you are dealing with `csv` files you might want to take a look at the `csv` library Python provides: [`csv` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

---

**On organisation**:

I really liked that you grouped related `print`s in functions to call repeatedly! One thing you might consider is factoring the different actions you take, depending on the `userInput` variable, into separate functions. That way, the body of your main function is cleaner and easier to read, and then you have a separate function for each functionality.

**On user input**:

Clever usage of `.lower()` to handle capitalised input ;)

You are doing relatively basic I/O, with the user just typing a single letter to pick an action. One thing you might want to do is

```py
userInput = input("\nEnter your Choice: ").trim().lower()
```

This removes leading/trailing whitespace (with `.trim`).
Additionally, you may want to also add `[0]` at the end of the line if it is acceptable for the user to write a whole word but you only need to use the first letter to distinguish. This doesn't make much sense while the actions are `a)`, `b)`, etc, but would make sense if you renamed the options to reflect what they actually do.

Good luck :)

Comment: Awesome :D Thank you so much, I'll start to incorporate that into my code in that case, I had no idea that is what the "with open" did. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Anytime! Python is _huge_, and while people often use Python to glue many different libraries, they forget that core Python has _plenty_ of useful and interesting features... The context managers being one of them :) I'll write about context managers [in my blog](https://mathspp.com/blog/pydonts) soon, because I love them so much!

Comment: Btw @JavierJose I updated the answer so be sure to check that.

Comment: Ahhh you're amazing! Thank you so much honestly... I'll be incorporating all your feedback into the project 100%. I'll also check out your blog ;)! Thank you again for all the help and time. :) You make me want to code more ahaha

Comment: @JavierJose coding can be a lot of fun, yes ;)